# Is there a way to list the connected devices on my wifi access point?

Tags: wifi, angstrom

I have an Angstrom Linux device acting as an access point, running `hostapd`, `dhcpd`, which works fine. Can I get a list of devices connected to the Wi-Fi? I know I can get the DHCP leases, but I need to know which devices connect through `wlan0`. I've tried this (`iwlist` has options):

```
iwlist wlan0 ap
iwlist wlan0 accesspoints
iwlist wlan0 peers
```

but all return:

```
wlan0     Interface doesn't have a list of Peers/Access-Points
```

`iwconfig`, `iwgetid`, `iwpriv` and `iwspy` are also present in `/sbin`, but don't seem to have options to display the client list.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should use [`iw dev wlan0 station dump`](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw#getting_station_statistics) as root

Comment: Thanks - I don't see this for my Arm 9 Angstrom yet, but I'll go look for it

Comment: Perhaps you can [compile from source](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/iw#Getting_iw), assuming you have enough space or a CF for temporary storage

Comment: iw also depends on nl80211 support in the WiFi interface's driver - which is not present for all drivers yet... https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/documentation/nl80211

Comment: In case you have more than one devices, for example when having 2.4 GHz and 5GHz enabled, you might get an empty results back. This is an indicator that no client has connected to the specify interface or frequency.

Comment: Also *i think* that if you have `wlan0.staX` (certain wds/multiap/4addr configs) you would need to specify that interface for all staX interfaces

Comment: The output of `iw -h` says at the end: `Do NOT screenscrape this tool, we don't consider its output stable.`

Comment: The above command as is will dump a lot of data. Just use i.e. `iw dev wlan1 station dump |grep "on wlan1"`

Answer (score 12):

You could Use "arp" as root:

```
$ sudo arp
```

or:

```
$ sudo arp | sort
```

kinda nicer, but you got the point :)

Comment: Not sure why should this be downvoted, it does show what kind of clients (IP and MAC) are connected

Comment: It is downvoted because arp returns only hosts that are active on the network in the arp table on the host. If someone nasty associates with the AP and is passively sniffing they will never show up in the arp table.

Comment: You don't need superuser privileges to dump the arp table. See also `ip n` on Linux.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I call arp but it only contains entries for ethernet. If i use arp -i wlan0 nothing is shown. With iw dev wlan0 station dump it is working.

Comment: arp is really just a mapping from L3 (IP) to L2 (MAC) addresses.  Deriving any information about connected stations is wrong.  Its a wrong place to look.  An could be a strict layer2 device and pass traffic without ever knowing the IP address of the AP.  So down-voting.

Answer (score 8):

You can also find list of connected devices to your AP by using this command:

```
cat /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases
```

dnsmasq.leases file lists all the devices which connected to AP so far.
Also you can get list of all devices which connected to your device over WiFi or Ethernet by using this command:

```
sudo arp
```

Comment: That would be on systems that use dnsmasq as a DHCP server. The OP uses "dhcpd", presumably the ISC implementation. Also stations could associate and not request and DHCP lease or not send any IP or ARP traffic.

Comment: AP does not need to be a DHCP server nor does it even need to understand/talk in IP, so both your suggestions are off

Answer (score 3):

### [`arp-scan`](http://www.nta-monitor.com/wiki/index.php/Arp-scan_User_Guide)

As said on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/628556/500826) you can use `arp-scan` package. Just `arp-scan -l`.

> arp-scan is a command-line tool for system discovery and fingerprinting. It constructs and sends ARP requests to the specified IP addresses, and displays any responses that are received.

With systemd/udev names I found very useful an alias to

```
sudo arp-scan -l -t 200 -I $(ls /sys/class/net | grep -o "wl[^\t]\+")
```

for the wireless interface and *en* instead of *wl* for wired interfaces.

- `-I --interface` Use network interface .  If this option is not specified, arp-scan will search the system interface list for the lowest numbered, configured up interface (excluding loopback).
- `-l --localnet` Generate  addresses from network interface configuration.  Use the network interface IP address and network mask to generate the list of target host addresses.
- `-t --timeout` Set initial per host timeout to  ms, default=100.  This timeout is for the first packet sent to each host.

To read the arp cache table cool kids nowadays use [`ip neighbor`](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-neighbor.html).

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this fast solution:

```
awk '$4~/[1-9a-f]+/&&$6~/^wl/{print "ip: "$1" mac: "$4}' /proc/net/arp
```

The `/[1-9a-f]/` filter removes MAC addresses like `00:00:00...` from listing.

The `/^wl/` filter removes all non-wireless interfaces (without "wl" at the beginning of their names).

The example result is:

```
ip: 192.168.0.1 mac: 64:6e:ea:d1:d3:0a
ip: 192.168.0.2 mac: a0:d3:a1:6d:d0:4a
```

Also, for my convenience, I use a file `macs` with list of mac addresses of this context:

```
90:94:97:9f:85:10 My Huawei
64:6e:ea:d1:d3:0a Rostelecom Router
```

To get a list of connected devices with parsing this file I use such command (the END section is unnecessary - it's an updater):

```
awk 'BEGIN{while((getline<"macs")>0){nmm=$0;gsub($1" ","",nmm);nmz[$1]=nmm}}$4~/[1-9a-f]+/&&$6~/^wl/{print $1 " " (nmz[$4]?nmz[$4]:$4);if(!nmz[$4]){nmz[$4]=$4;update=1}}END{if(update){system("gawk -f macupd.awk")}}' /proc/net/arp
```

So in this way the result will be:

```
192.168.0.1 Rostelecom Router
192.168.0.74 My Huawei
```

The `macupd.awk` is the script for updating `macs` file. It gets vendor names from file [oui.txt](http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui/oui.txt) (located in the same directory) and uses them as descriptions of unknown hosts/clients connected to your machine and writes them to the `macs` list file (you may disable this by removing END section from command). Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN{
    while((getline<"macs")>0){
        str++
        if($0!~"(^#|^$)"){
            nam=$0
            gsub($1" ","",nam)
            macnamz[$1]=nam
        }
    }

    while((getline<"/proc/net/arp")>0){
        if($4~/[1-9a-f]+/&&$6~/^wl/){
            if(!macnamz[$4]){
                mac=macv=$4
                gsub(":","",macv)
                vendor=substr(macv,1,6)
                rs=RS
                RS="\n|\r"
                while((getline<"oui.txt")>0){
                    if(toupper($1)~toupper(vendor)){gsub(/.*\t+/,"");macnamz[mac]=$0;update=1}
                }
                RS=rs
            }
        }
    }
    if(update){
        for(i in macnamz){print i " " macnamz[i] > "macs"}
        print "" > "macs"
    }
}
```

So if in the **first** running of my imperfect command the result will be (if all hosts where unknown):

```
192.168.10.1 00:d0:ef:aa:ee:ff
192.168.10.2 f4:bd:9e:00:00:00
192.168.10.3 00:22:72:11:22:33
```

The **second** running will be such:

```
192.168.10.1 IGT
192.168.10.2 Cisco Systems, Inc
192.168.10.3 American Micro-Fuel Device Corp.
```

The description of my script.

`getline<"macs"` - Reading lines from list

`if($0!~"(^#|^$)")` - Ignoring commented and empty lines.

`gsub($1" ","",nam)` - I used `nam` variable for description (everything after space).

`macnamz[$1]=nam` - Final conversion of line to a part of associative array (there can not be 2 duplicated MACs - 2nd will overwrite 1st).

`getline<"/proc/net/arp"` - Getting connected IPs and MACs.

`if($4~/[1-9a-f]+/&&$6~/^wl/)` - Filtering out header line, zero MACs, and non-wireless interfaces.

`if(!macnamz[$4])` - If connected device is not registered in our `macs` file.

`gsub(":","",macv)` and `vendor=substr(macv,1,6)` - Getting first 6 symbols of MAC.

`RS="\n|\r"` - Because `oui.txt` may have MS Windows line endings.

`gsub(/.*\t+/,"")` - Removing tabs

`macnamz[mac]=$0` - Converting line to an array member.

`update=1` - This variable says that updating of file is necessary (if it is).

Comment: Doesn't this also list devices connected by wired interfaces?  I just tried on a non-WiFi machine, and got results corresponding to its Ethernet interfaces.  Perhaps we need`$6 ~ /wlan/` as the condition instead.  Note, your version also misses some addresses - the char group should be `[0-9a-f]`.

Comment: Does. If you want to show only wi-fi connections use '$4~/[1-9]+/&&$6~/^wl/' (my wlan device name is wlo1). My solution shows all connected network devices (your router and your clients) with ip and mac.The "[1-9]" I use to filter such: 00:00:00:00... mac addresses. So I'm not wrong :-) (a little bit wrong! "[1-9a-f]" will be correct). Maybe the 0x2 flag is router and 0x0 is client, I don't know. In my case it is.

Answer (score 0):

the accepted answer is of course correct but some systems might be too old (or some drivers) for `iw`

if you have `hostapd` you probably also have `hostapd_cli`, so you can try

```
hostapd_cli list_sta
```

I down-voted any answer that was not `iw` because they rely on traffic actually traversing the link.  Getting a list of think connected to your wifi should not depend on those things making higher level (OSI model-wise).

Comment: Not everyone's got hostapd in use. iw, however, is present on most systems deploying wifi interfaces and `iw dev <wifi-IF> station dump` ought to work anyway. To just see the list of connected stations, i.e. use `iw dev wlan1 station dump |grep "on wlan1"`

Comment: @Gen.Stack just so were clear I did not throw shade at the `iw` answers.  Where available that's fine but it is a relatively a newer interface and, from experience, `iw`  is just not available everywhere.  As you noted yeah `hostapd` is not  always used.  I have not had the pleasure of using `iwd` but  i thought it was rare to have no mgmt daemon at all.

Answer (score -1):

There is also a free (commercial licence, unlimited duration trial with maximum of 5 devices displayed) GUI application, [WifiGuard](https://www.softperfect.com/products/wifiguard/).

Comment: WifiGuard is for Windows and macOS only.

Answer (score -2):

On Ubuntu, After starting the hotspots by clicking in WiFi top right of screen in gnome, select WiFi and "Wi-Fi Settings", config opens, select hamburger top right in menu, "Turn On Wi-Fi Hotspot..."

In terminal display connected clients by running in superuser mode :

```
iw dev wlan0 station dump
```

Comment: how does this answe differ from the accepted one - that was submitted years before yours?

Comment: it explains how to enable hotspots through the gui