# Maximum clients with USB hotspot

Tags: linux, debian, dnsmasq, hostapd, access-point

I made a small access point using Hostapd, Dnsmasq and Debian Wheezy.

I'm using an USB dongle, how could I know the maximum number of clients allowed? Can I change it?
How can I manage (disconnect, see status, etc.) a connected client?

Comment: I'd *guess* there is no specific limitation; you're just dividing bandwidth.  So you could have hundreds or thousands of clients (if you could get them close enough), as long as they are only transferring a limited amount of data each.  But that's a guess not an answer...in any case, the limitation probably won't be because of the OS, so you might want to ask that specific question on SuperUser instead.

Comment: I think you can find out info about the station using the info described here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40087/is-there-a-way-to-list-the-connected-devices-on-my-wifi-access-point and here: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw#Getting_station_statistics