# command to see no of wifi clients/Mac address of clients connected to near by access points(SSIDs)

Tags: linux, terminal, wifi, iw

apart from airodump command can we use any other command to see how many wi-fi clients are associated to access points

Comment: First rule of using tools is understanding them. It is a wrong premise believing airodump will show you all the wifi-clients to the nearby APs, for several reasons that are clearly out of topic here. I would also avoid Kali.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to list the connected devices on my wifi access point?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40087/is-there-a-way-to-list-the-connected-devices-on-my-wifi-access-point)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo nmap -sn <ip addr of your router>/24
```

- this scans all the devices connected to your AP.

Read nmap documentation for more.
really handy tool to learn about.